# Extjs 4 with Sencha Touch Scrollbar

Tags: scroll, sencha-touch, extjs4

Is there a way to import Sencha Touch Scrollbar Engine inside a ExtJs 4 application?
I'm developing a smart application for desktop environment that uses a touch-screen monitor and I would to merge the power of ExtJs with this touch interaction of Sencha Touch.

Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't use the Sencha Touch itself for building your app? It is alomost similar to ExtJs.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no. You can't mix Touch and ExtJs.